# How to choose Maven, Ivy, or SBT for an Artifactory local repository?

Tags: scala, maven, sbt, artifactory, ivy

Similar questions have been asked, but their answers are unsatisfactory. It boils down to: what are the best practices and consequences of choosing Maven, Ivy, or SBT for a repository when working primarily (but not exclusively) with SBT and Scala? For background, Maven is the only one which appears to work correctly. When artifacts are published by SBT using Maven style (with `publishMavenStyle := true`) Artifactory is able to correctly identify the module id. and offer instructions for how to add the artifact as a dependency to various build systems. Of course, it doesn't account for Scala versions in the module name (*i.e.*, it doesn't recommend the use of SBT's `%%` operator for artifacts built against Scala), and it prohibits publishing SBT plugins (with 409 errors) when consistency checks are enabled (which are obviously desirable). In the latter cases—for Ivy and SBT—the layout patterns are similar, and [the patterns even appear interchangeable according to SBT's documentation](http://scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Proxy-Repositories.html) where an Ivy proxy is configured with the same pattern specified by `sbt-default` layout in Artifactory. However, artifacts published here by SBT (with `publishMavenStyle := false`) don't appear to be properly recognized by Artifactory (contrary to earlier mention, the module id. is always “N/A” and no build tool instructions appear) leading me to assume they're not checked for consistency or indexed correctly. Of course, it doesn't help that SBT itself doesn't even appear capable of publishing artifacts with either the prescribed Ivy or SBT patterns. Ultimately, I'm hesitant to make decisions regarding my repository setups given the long-term ramifications and how the tools (SBT and Artifactory) don't seem to work as I'd expect.

Comment: I think this is actually a very good question to post to SO.  "Build" is an important part of "development" ... and there AREN'T as mature and robust solutions for Scala as Maven/Gradle (for Java) or NuGet (for C#/.Net) in Scala.  Look here [Building Scala Projects: Maven vs. SBT](http://www.hammerlab.org/2017/04/06/scala-build-tools/).  Also look at [Pants](https://www.pantsbuild.org/)